# How to Map two different table data in single object using Composite class (data mapping C#)

Tags: c#

I am facing an issue regarding mapping composite class. Data comes from Server in a Dataset which is dsSubjectMarks, and I am unable to map Because it contains two subject Angular and React with difference Rows For Example Angular Having 2 rows and react having 4 Rows in Dataset. I want to make a object of composite class having all the data in single object, Here is the code:

```
public static List<ExamComposite> BindResult(DataSet dsSubjectMarks, int RollNO)
{
   var Angular = dsSubjectMarks.Tables[0];
   var React = dsSubjectMarks.Tables[1];
   var Rno = RollNO;
   var mListExamComposite = new List<ExamComposite>();

   if (Angular.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
        foreach (DataRow dr in Angular.Rows)
        {
            var _ExamComposite= new ClaimLineComposite
            {
                // Code for mapping
            };

            mListExamComposite .Add(_ExamComposite);
        }
    }
    return mListExamComposite ;
}

namespace ExamManager_Controller.Composite
{
    public class ExamComposite : PocoBase
    {
        public List<ExamCompositList> Exam_Comp_Data { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ExamManager_Controller.Atomic
{
    public class ExamCompositeList:PocoBase
    {
        public Anguar _Anguar { get; set; }
        public React _React { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ExamManager_Controller.Atomic
{
    public class Anguar : PocoBase
    {
        public string version{ get; set; }
        public string User{ get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ExamManager_Controller.Atomic
{
    public class React: PocoBase
    {
        public string version{ get; set; }
        public string User{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: [MCVE] is needed. The React table is not used.

Comment: Yes the react table is not used,  that is what i want to know how to use both table to get single object of ExamComposite type.

Comment: just do another for each using the React table adding the values to the same  ExamComposite type